# How to solve function without expanding

Tags: calculus

I have an integral, and the function is pretty big, so I know there is an easier way of simplifying the function without expanding but I'm not sure.

I have...

$$F(r(t)) = 1/3(t^3 -6t^2 +11t)^2i + 1/3(t^3-6t^2+11t)j$$

and...

$$r(t)' = 1/3(3t^2-12t+11)i + (3t^2-12t+11)j$$

Now I find the dot product....

$$(1/3(t^3 -6t^2 +11t)^2i + 1/3(t^3-6t^2+11t)j)*(1/3(3t^2-12t+11)i + (3t^2-12t+11)j)$$

This leaves me with a crazy long equation that I don't want to expand. How can I simplify this?

Comment: Recall that $i \cdot j = j \cdot i = 0$, and observe that for both $F(r(t))$ and $r'(t)$ the $i$ and $j$ coefficients agree, up to an overall factor, so the dot product is just some multiple of $(t^3 - 6 t^2 + 11 t)^2 (3 t^2 - 12 t + 11)$. Now, the second term is the derivative of the first, suggesting a natural substitution to evaluate the resulting integral in $t$...